# Check Hard disk status with RAID 5 configuration in Centos 6

Tags: centos, raid, monitoring

I have a PC with 6 HDD (for data) and 1 SSD (for Centos 6.3) with on board intel RAID 5.
I'm pretty aware that upon any hard disk failure the system will continue normally but more stress on the CPU to compute the parity, but how I can be aware that really a hard disk is corrupted and needs to be replaced?

Can the OS be aware of any hard disk failure? If not which part of the BIOS can notify me?

Comment: You might get answers in http://serverfault.com/

Comment: seriously, why all the hate!

Comment: Not really a question for this site but -3 is harsh